# What happens to saved scriptable objects when an update is downloaded?

Tags: c#, updates, unity-game-engine

So I have some scriptable objects which, for the time being are storing a bit of information and changing a bool at runtime.

I want this bool to persist between sessions. with no update it of course does this fine.

However, say I launch this current version, and users use the game, and set some of the bools from false to true. If I release an update, that update will have all bools defaulted to false, when they apply the update would they lose the true's they set on any of their scriptable objects?

If not, could you explain why this isnt the case as I don't understand how that could be?

If so, then I assume the best solution would be to store a list of the scriptable objects which have had their bool's set to true, and upon launhc reset these as required? Is there anything more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

Store the bools with `PlayerPrefs`. When next session is started, first thing to do is to check if the `bool` exist on the drive. If it does, load it and override the default `bool` with the loaded `bool`.

If the `bool` does not exist, save the current default `bool` for next time. On game exist (OnDisable) or other similar callback functions, save the bool. That's all you have to do. It will always be there until  `PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll` or `PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey` is called to clear it.

Below is a complete example. It checks if sound is enabled and it is well commented:

```
bool soundOn = false;

//Check if soundOn key Exist (return -1 if it doesn't exist)
if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("soundOn", -1) == -1)
{
    //It doesn't exist. Now save the current value
    if (soundOn)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("soundOn", 1);
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("soundOn", 0);
    }
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
//soundOn key Exist. Now Load it and override soundOn bool
else
{
    int tempBool = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("soundOn");
    if (tempBool == 0)
    {
        soundOn = false;

    }
    else if (tempBool == 1)
    {
        soundOn = true;
    }
}
```

You can convert it into a function that is re-usable and will work with any variable.

Comment: I can save the bool, but I was wondering would it definitely be overwritten in the ScriptableObject when the user updates, or would it persist?

Comment: @MatthewParker I know you can save the bool and I answered that part of the question too. **It will always be there until  PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll or PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey is called to clear it.** So it won't be overwritten. It will be there and as long as you did not overwrite it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the scriptable object. If the scriptable object has its bool set to true, will this be overtritten upon update, or would it remain as the master version?

Comment: @MatthewParker I am a bit confused. **overtritten upon update** what do you mean by that?

Comment: Player downloads my app and runs it. During runtime, Some scriptable objects, which store a bool (and other stuff), are changed so that the bool says true instead of false. (they all started out as false when the user downloaded the app). I release an update, and the user downloads the update. What happens to those scriptable objects now? Do the bools they changed to true stay true, or do they chane to false as that is what they have redownloaded from the update? Which scriptable object takes precidance whilst applying the update, the one they already have or the one they downloaded?

Comment: @MatthewParker I see what are you asking now. First of all, please understand that `ScriptableObject` should NOT be used to save game data. That should be used in the Editor during edit time only. You have to save it as an asset to be able to use it in game. Any ways, can you post the code you are using save the  `ScriptableObject` and modify it ? That I can use to answer your question.